# Need help with polar double integral problem

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

this is an even problem in my textbook. So this is one of the few places I 
can check my answer.

$$\int _{-1}^1\int _{-\sqrt{1\:-\:x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\:\frac{2}{\left(1\:+\:x^2\:+\:y^2\right)^2}\:dy\:dx$$

this is what I converted it to

$$\int _0^{2\pi }\int _0^1\:\frac{2r}{\left(1\:+\:r^2\right)^2}\:dr\:d\theta $$

I'm not sure if this is the correct conversion.
If it is indeed correct, how should go about integrating it?

Comment: that looks good! you may use wolfram to double check answers : [cartesian](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+_%7B-1%7D%5E1%5Cint+_%7B-%5Csqrt%7B1%5C%3A-%5C%3Ax%5E2%7D%7D%5E%7B%5Csqrt%7B1-x%5E2%7D%7D%5C%3A%5Cfrac%7B2%7D%7B%5Cleft%281%5C%3A%2B%5C%3Ax%5E2%5C%3A%2B%5C%3Ay%5E2%5Cright%29%5E2%7D%5C%3Ady%5C%3Adx) and [polar](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint+_0%5E%7B2%5Cpi+%7D%5Cint+_0%5E1%5C%3A%5Cfrac%7B2r%7D%7B%5Cleft%281%5C%3A%2B%5C%3Ar%5E2%5Cright%29%5E2%7D%5C%3Adr%5C%3Ad%5Ctheta). There is a very obvious u sub to evaluate that : $$u = 1+r^2$$

Comment: @ganeshie8 thanks. U-substitution.....tsk.tsk. I was killing myself trying to set this up for integration by parts.

Comment: @lasec0203 Instead of prepending `(Solved)` to the title, you should either ask ganeshie8 to write his comment as an answer or write an answer yourself and accept it. This will mark the question as answered by the system so it disappears from the unanswered list etc.

Comment: @AlexR ok, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct. Readily recognizable integrate $ \frac{-1}{1+r^2}.. $

Answer (score 0):

$$\int _{-1}^1\int _{-\sqrt{1\:-\:x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\:\frac{2}{\left(1\:+\:x^2\:+\:y^2\right)^2}\:dy\:dx$$

convert the integral above to:

$$\int _0^{2\pi }\int _0^1\:\frac{2r}{\left(1\:+\:r^2\right)^2}\:dr\:d\theta $$

use U-sub: $$\:u\:=\:1\:+\:r^2$$

$$\int _0^{2\pi }\int _1^2\:\frac{1}{u^2}\:dud\theta $$

integrate the inner integral and get

$$ \int _0^{2\pi }\:\frac{1}{2}\:d\theta $$

integrate above and get

$$ \frac{1}{2}\left(2\pi \right)\:-\:\frac{1}{2}\left(0\right)\:=\:\pi  $$